# Why output is empty after function zRangeByScore?

Tags: php, redis, node-redis, phpredis

I use a php extension for Redis.
There is a simple code:

```
$result = $this->redis->zUnion('mergedArr', array('FEED:User:459', 'FEED:User:458'));
var_dump($result); // It is returns 15 integer

$start = time();
$end = strtotime("+5 day");
$result = $this->redis->zRangeByScore('mergedArr', $start, $end, array('limit' => array(1, 1), 'withscores' => TRUE));


echo '<pre>';
   var_dump($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

At first line I merge two `KEYS` to a new array(`KEY`) `mergedArr`.
Then in line 4 I tried to get limited and sorted data from `mergedArr` by score from 7 last days.

Why I get empty `$result`?

Documentation [phpredis](https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis/#zrangebyscore-zrevrangebyscore)

Comment: Use MONITOR to understand what is exactly sent to Redis. Probably one of the parameters, or perhaps the value of the score, is not what you think it is.